# Javascript Heavy Scripting Load(Lags the website)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, highcharts, lag

I have the website that runs on javascript 1.7.1 and everytime i click a button that runs the Javascript method, the web load becomes far more heavier and continuously run the javascript up to the point that the site starts to lag.Here is an example of my JS method:

```
 function makeGraph() {

        var cityValue = [];
        var cityValue2 = [];
        var cityName = [];
        var numIndex = [];
        var tDelivery = [];
        var tIdle = [];
        var tRepair = [];
        var tReady = [];
        var barColor = "";
        var cityString = "";
        var chrt = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var cityList = [];
        cityList = arguments;

        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                for (var j = 1; j < cityList.length; j++)
                {
                    cityString = cityString + "||" + " data[i].Names==\"" + cityList[j] + "\"";
                }    
                cityString = "data[i].Names==\"" + cityList[0] + "\""+cityString;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (eval(cityString)) {
                        numIndex.push(i);
                    }

                }
                for (var k = 0; k < numIndex.length; k++) {
                    cityValue.push(data[numIndex[k]].ValuesDouble);
                    cityValue2.push(data[numIndex[k]].ValuesDouble2);
                    cityName.push(data[numIndex[k]].Names);
                    tDelivery.push(data[numIndex[k]].truckDelivery);
                    tIdle.push(data[numIndex[k]].truckIdle);
                    tRepair.push(data[numIndex[k]].truckRepair);
                    tReady.push(data[numIndex[k]].truckReady);
                }
                if (numIndex.length > 0) {
                    for (var h = 0; h < numIndex.length - 1; h++) {
                        barColor = barColor + "{y:" + cityValue2[h] + ",color:'" + setGraphColor(cityValue2[h], cityValue[h]) + "'}" + ",";
                    }
                    barColor = "[" + barColor + "{y:" + cityValue2[numIndex.length-1] + ",color:'" + setGraphColor(cityValue2[numIndex.length-1],cityValue[numIndex.length-1]) + "'}" + "]";
                }
                else {
                    barColor = "[" + barColor + "{y:" + data[numIndex[0]].ValuesDouble2 + ",color:'" + setGraphColor(data[numIndex[0]].ValuesDouble2, data[numIndex[0]].ValuesDouble) + "'}" + "]";
                }

                $(function () {
                    Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            backgroundColor: 'black'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/><div>__________________________</div><hr>';

                                $.each(this.points, function () {
                                    s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span><b>' + this.series.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
                                });

                                return s;
                            },
                            shared: true
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: cityName,

                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            tickInterval: 500,
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            reversed: false,
                            backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                stacking: 'normal'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Daily Schedule',
                            data: eval(barColor)
                        },
                       {
                           name: 'Actual Delivery',
                           data: cityValue,
                           color: '#33FF66'
                       },
                       {
                           name: '0%-69%',
                           //data: cityValue,
                           color: '#FF3366'
                       },
                        {
                            name: '70%-89%',
                           // data: cityValue,
                            color: '#FFCC33'
                        },
                       {
                           name: '90%-100%',
                          // data: cityValue,
                           color: '#003DF5'
                       }]
                    });
                });

                //////////////GRAPH 2 INFLUENCE///////////
                $(function () {
                    Highcharts.chart('container2', {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            backgroundColor: 'black'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/><div>__________________________</div><hr>';

                                $.each(this.points, function () {
                                    s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span><b>' + this.series.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
                                });

                                return s;
                            },
                            shared: true
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: cityName,

                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            max:80,
                            tickInterval: 20,
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            reversed: false,
                            backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                stacking: 'normal'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [
                        {
                            name: 'Truck Delivery',
                            data: tDelivery,
                            color: '#33FF66'

                        },
                         {
                             name: 'Truck Idle',
                             data: tIdle,
                             color: '#FFCC33'
                         },
                         {
                             name: 'Truck Repair',
                             data: tRepair,
                             color: '#FF3366'
                         },
                        {
                            name: 'Truck Ready',
                            data: tReady,
                            color: '#003DF5'
                        }]
                    });
                });

                //////////////GRAPH 3 INFLUENCE///////////
                $(function () {
                    Highcharts.chart('container3', {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            backgroundColor: 'black'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/><div>__________________________</div><hr>';

                                $.each(this.points, function () {
                                    s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span><b>' + this.series.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
                                });

                                return s;
                            },
                            shared: true
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: cityName,

                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            tickInterval: 500,
                            title: {
                                text: ''
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            reversed: false,
                            backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                stacking: 'normal'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [
                        {
                            name: 'Staff On Duty',
                            data: cityValue,
                            color: '#33FF66'

                        },
                         {
                             name: 'Staff Present',
                             data: cityValue,
                             color: '#003DF5'
                         },
                        {
                            name: 'Staff Absent',
                            data: cityValue,
                            color: '#FF3366'
                        }]
                    });
                });

            }
        })

    }
```

I also have run a developer tool in IE 11 which shows me that it is indeed from the nonstop javascript loop. I was wondering if anyone could help me stop the JS loop so that it is not continuous.(I am also using SignalR and i dont know if this is one of the factors).Thanks in advance.

These are the header tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/highcharts/4.2.0/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and yes, I am using highchart.js in this function and the button is that so i can refresh and sort the graph according to the buttons i clicked which in these cases are categories of cities.

Comment: it seems only you know the problem. can you please provide more description like how you initialised all js files, how you determined its endless Js loop?
note: JS always has the problem of priority i.e . in which manner you have initialized

Comment: I always initialize all my JS methods with ajax so that i can GET from it and execute on success as seen above. As for how i determine the endless loop, is when i try to run the Developer tools, in the network tab, imediately as i click the button that calls the method the GET keeps showing endlessly json/application it says. Also, in the performance tab, the Javascript bar spikes up as i clicked. And in the memory tab, the memory keeps rising constantly which i think triggers the lag.@DirtyDeveloper thats why i think its a loop(even though theres none)

Comment: mate, can you please post the design page here? I can see only one function. can you please share the header tag where you have initialised the JS?
sorry mate, want to help but not able to understand your question

Comment: looking the the code something pops up in my head. you have used highcharts.js, right? can you try please commenting that and have a look?? also, you are calling ajax everytime for filling the dropdown? this ajax will be fired everytime page gets refreshed.

Comment: The ajax has no problem on page startup since i called it to show the initial graph. I dont know why but the trigger is the button and the lag start when and if i press the button . @DirtyDeveloper I really appreciate your help